# What does a UISegmentedControl return to its action on UIControlEventValueChanged?

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

So, I have a UISegmentedControl with:

`[control addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Just wondering how I would find out what segment has been selected (so I can do the appropriate action). I know its something like:

`@selector(myAction:)` but what gets sent? ie: when I define my method what do I have to define?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

get the selected item... second part of question

```
-(IBAction) myAction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"myAction",nil);

    UISegmentedControl * control = sender;
    int selectedIndex = [control selectedSegmentIndex];
}
```

Comment: ah brilliant... my problem was that I was trying: `int selectedIndex = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];` and not adding it to an object. :) brilliant, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)selector;
```

selector is an UISegmentedControl object. Thus you may differ two UISegmentedControl's if you bind one action to both.

Comment: right brilliant, so - sorry to be thick ha, but what about deciding which particular segment was selected (especially as I have momentary:YES)? thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is also easier way:

```
-(IBAction) myAction:(UISegmentedControl*)control {
   NSLog(@"selected index %d", control.selectedSegmentIndex);
}
```